# Getting Empty list while doing inner join in SqLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, join, android-sqlite

I have two table which have define as:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(
                "create table medicine " +
                        "(medId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , medName TEXT NOT NULL, imgPath TEXT NOT NULL, alarmScheduleDate INTEGER NOT NULL, lastDateForAlarm INTEGER NOT NULL )"
       );



sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(
                "create table reminderinfo " +
                        "(remId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , medId INTEGER NOT NULL, remTime INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                        " medDose INTEGER NOT NULL, medCatogory TEXT NOT NULL," +
                        "foreign key(medId) REFERENCES medicine(medId))"
        );
```

**I want to join these two table using the inner join with some condition.**

join these two table on medId where medCatogory=userinput

**My Attempt:**

```
String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM medicine INNER JOIN reminderinfo ON medicine.medId = reminderinfo.medId WHERE reminderinfo.medCatogory="+ selectedCatagory;

db.rawQuery(rawQuery,null);
```

result:-

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: userinput
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM medicine INNER JOIN
>   reminderinfo ON medicine.medId = reminderinfo.medId WHERE
>   reminderinfo.medCatogory=userinput

userinput is catagory name given by user

case 2:-

```
String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM medicine INNER JOIN reminderinfo ON medicine.medId = reminderinfo.medId
```

Getting empty array.

I have tried both the query using SQLitebrowser 
and getting desired result

Comment: You'll need to provide more info for the case 2. I saw the create table statements however your empty result might be just an issue with the actual data. I was looking in the android api, you might adjust your insert as described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])

Comment: What other I need to provide for the case 2 @Sombriks. And I saw the databases It have values but I don't get the region why It is returning empty array.

Comment: I mean the data available on those two tables. you have your join condition however if there is no data you'll get such empty result.

Comment: That also I checked, the data is sufficient @Sombriks

Comment: try to query the .sqlite file with http://sqlitebrowser.org/ . if it works outside android then you just might be looking at the wrong db file.

Comment: I tried and getting output for my both the queries using sqlitebrowser @Sombriks